# Use api2pdf to save PDF to specific folder on server

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to convert web page to PDF and the PDF also needs to be saved in one specific folder on my shared server. It saves to the device's default folder: "downloads", but I also need to save the file on my server:

````
$api_key = '';
$filename = 'Agreement.pdf';
$url = '../agreement-buyer.php';

$postData = json_encode(array(
    'url' => $url,
    'options' => $options
));

$headers = array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: ' . $api_key
);

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $endpoint,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postData,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
if (!curl_errno($curl)) {
    $http_code = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    if ($http_code === 200) {
        $response_obj = json_decode($response);
        $pdf_url = $response_obj->FileUrl;
        
        // Download the PDF file with the set filename
        header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
        
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $pdf_url);
        curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
    } else {
        echo 'Error generating PDF. HTTP code: ' . $http_code;
        exit;
    }
} else {
    echo 'Error generating PDF: ' . curl_error($curl);
    exit;
}
curl_close($curl);
unset($_GET);
unset($_POST); ```

What line of code and where do I put it to save to a folder on my server?
````

Comment: Your code, at least what you put in your question, doesn't yet produce a valid PDF file. Why not start with that and then worry about saving it on the server? Or, to put it another way: How can we help you if we don't know what you're doing?

Comment: one more question? Now that all is doing what is requested... please, why is the server pdf have no contents while the download does? - meaning, the pdf on the server is blank.

Comment: Both should have the same content, if you properly used my answer. Pay special attention to the usage, in 3 places, of the `$content` variable.

Comment: Got it! I had to change ur code from ```array($curl``` to ```array($ch```

Comment: Ah, yes, I made a mistake there copying your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, you're already using `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` in one of the cURLs. Why not use it in the other? Something like this:

```
    // Download the PDF file with the set filename
    header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
    
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, [CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                              CURLOPT_URL            => $pdf_url]);
    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    // output to browser
    echo $content;

    // save to file on server
    file_put_contents("myFile.pdf", $content);
```

Having